# RestAssured LogConfig.blacklistedHeaders error

Tags: rest-assured, cucumber-java, serenity-bdd

I am getting below error when run `serenity-cucumber6` test with rest-assured.

```
Step failed
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.restassured.config.LogConfig.blacklistedHeaders()Ljava/util/Set;
    at net.serenitybdd.rest.utils.RestReportingHelper.registerCall(RestReportingHelper.java:69)
    at net.serenitybdd.rest.decorators.request.RequestSpecificationDecorated.reportQuery(RequestSpecificationDecorated.java:292)
    at net.serenitybdd.rest.decorators.request.RequestSpecificationDecorated.execute(RequestSpecificationDecorated.java:284)
    at net.serenitybdd.rest.decorators.request.RequestSpecificationDecorated.get(RequestSpecificationDecorated.java:67)
    at net.serenitybdd.rest.decorators.request.RequestSpecificationDecorated.get(RequestSpecificationDecorated.java:38)
```

The versions I am using are:

```
    <spring-boot.version>2.4.5</spring-boot.version>
    <serenity.plugin.version>2.4.34</serenity.plugin.version>
    <serenity.version>2.4.34</serenity.version>
    <serenity.cucumber.version>2.4.34</serenity.cucumber.version>
    <cucumber.version>6.10.4</cucumber.version>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
```

The test main class

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
import net.serenitybdd.cucumber.CucumberWithSerenity;

@RunWith(CucumberWithSerenity.class)
@CucumberOptions(
    plugin = {"pretty", "html:target/reports/cucumber-html-report",
        "html:target/cucumber-reports/cucumber-pretty",
        "json:target/cucumber.json"},
    tags = "not @skip",
    glue = {"my.stepdefinitions"},
    features = "src/it/resources/features/")

public class MyServiceCucumberTests {
}
```

Request call method

```
public static Response request(Function<RequestSpecification, Response> method, RequestSpecification spec) {
    RequestSpecification call = rest()
        .spec(spec)
        .when();
    return method.apply(call)
        .then()
        .extract().response();
}
```